# Skyrim's screenshot are distorted and black & white.

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

So I've been naively pressing PrtSc to capture all he cool stuff I've seen or done so far.  (like about a million of funny bugs)

But when I went to see the images, I was about as dissapointed as when I last forgot to remove my camera objective cover:

[image: image description]

The question is whether those images can be restored. They have `.bmp` extension but MsPaint doesn't recognize them, so maybe they are in some Bethesda's proprietary format, is that possible?

And if not, is there at least a way to prevent this from happening and get nice screenshots? I tried also the Steam's F12, but that doesn't do anything at all - how surprising.

Comment: They have no proprietary format. Also check your steam settings for screenshots

Comment: I used to take a lot of screenshots with steam and just with the print screen button and I never had any problem on Skyrim with it.
Is that the only game you have trouble with ?

Answer (score 1):

I could recreate the problem by setting the resolution to 1366x768, so I'm assuming the problem is that Bethesda games can't deal with weird aspect ratios (like 683:384).

But the Steam screenshot (F12 by default) should work without problem, **unless of course the steam overlay is disabled**.

So if the overlay is disabled I would suggest you turn it back on, to do that:

1. Set the global setting in Steam/Settings/In-Game:

   - Enable the steam overlay while in-game
   - Check the screenshot key(F12), and notification
2. Set the Skyrim properties, right click in game list than Properties

   - Check Enable the steam overlay while in-game here too

After this the in-game overlay (shift + tab) and the screenshot should work too.

If this does not work, you could try using [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/download.php) I heard it works well for Skyrim screenshots.

Or you could try changing your resolution to something more common, and if you have shader mods installed (ENB,FXAA PP Injector,etc), try disabling them.